# DjangoRestFramework - How do I customize the frontend?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, frontend

This is my basic view using DjangoRestFramework:

```
class user_list(APIView):
    """
    List all users, or create a new user.
    """
    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I go to the URL which calls this view (localhost:8000/CMS/users), DjangoRestFramework already has a frontend which says:

```
GET /CMS/users
HTTP 200 OK
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {
        "username": "t",
    }
]
```

How do I customize this? I want to use AngularJS on the frontend. I know that without DjangoRestFramework, I would return an html template which would be located in my Django App directory in a folder called "Templates". I've been told that DjangoRestFramework is useful becauase I can create a RESTful API which returns JSON objects. I tried adding the following to my settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```

but I still can't seem to figure out how I can customize the frontend of my Django application. I know that there is:

```
renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
```

in which I can return an html page in my view, like so:

```
return Response({'user': self.object}, template_name='user_detail.html')
```

but doesn't returning actual HTML pages defeat the purpose of DjangoRestFramework's ability to return JSON objects and create a RESTful API?

Answer (score 2):

First off, there are some things to make Django Rest Framework play better with angular.  Until I decided to try out ember, I was working through [this utorial](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html).  To try to provide a useful example for your question:

1. Typically you want to put your DjangoRestFramework REST Api in something like /api.
2. If you're doing the seemingly ubiquitiious single page application, you can then have index.html get served up as a template (i.e. just have your default home view be a TemplateView with index.html as the template)
3. You would then have your angular html templates and your angular/jquery/etc. javsascripts and your css files as normal static files.  NB that you generally don't want to have django templates generate angular code.  First off, it makes things much more of a pain to debug, and secondly, the default angular and django template syntax use the same <% characters meaning you have to be careful to make sure one doesn't try to interpret the others templating code.

When you load http://yourserver/, this will bring up the index.html page which then pulls down angular stuff, which then starts making RESTful calls to your REST api to generate the data.  Note that you can start mixing in stuff to use Django forms etc., but I'd recommend keeping it simple and then reading the linked article (or another) once you have the basics going.

Comment: when you say "Typically you want to put your DjangoRestFramework REST Api in something like /api." do you mean I want the DRF API as it's own app? Or in it's own folder where the settings.py file is located? Because in the tutorial you linked to ( https://github.com/kevinastone/django-api-rest-and-angular/tree/master/example/api ), it seems as if "example" is the project and "api" is a folder inside where the 'settings.py' file is. It looks like 'api' is basically it's own app (has models.py, serializers.py and urls.py) but just doesn't have views.py. The setup is a bit confusing.